# renderizado de lineas c++

Tags: c++, c, c++builder

estoy llevando haciendo un programa que dibuje lineas a base del algoritmo simple (ecuación de la recta), pero sucede que los pixeles a colorear se dispersan mucho para una linea de puntos:

x0=30    x1=50
y0=100   y1=10
Como puedo solucionarlo, este el codigo que estuve haciendo:

```
void dibujo(int x0,int y0,int x1,int y1){
    //int dx=x0<x1 ? x1-x0 : x0-x1;
    //int dy=x0<x1 ? y1-y0 : y0-y1;
    int dx=x1-x0;
    int dy=y1-y0;
    bool ver=dx>dy || x0>x1 ? true : false;
    float m=ver ? (float)dy/dx: (float)dx/dy;
    float b=ver ? y0-m*x0 : x0-m*y0;
    float x=x0,y=y0;
    float *dir=ver ? &x : &y;
    int *dir1=ver ? &x1 : &y1;
    if(ver==true) dx=dx<0 ? -1 : 1;
    else dy=dy<0 ? -1 : 1;
    while(*dir!=*dir1){
        if(ver==true)y=m*x+b;
        else x=m*y+b;
        Form1->Canvas->Pixels[x][y]=clRed;
        if(ver==true)x+=dx;
        else y+=dy;
        //Sleep(10);
    }
}
```

ese es el resultado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar un poco lo que hace el código y para que usas algunas variables? Está todo junto y los nombres no son muy descriptivos. Además, con una sola llamada a la función `dibujo` se dibuja la línea entera o solo un punto?

Comment: La pendiente de tu recta (`m`) es `-4.5`, eso significa que te estás desplazando (en vertical) más de cuatro píxeles por cada píxel que quieres pintar; si no hicieses saltos tan grandes sería una línea sólida en lugar de punteada. Por cierto, tu código es un galimatías incomprensible, he tenido que reorganizar el código para entenderlo (y aún así no entiendo la mayoría de decisiones que has tomado).

Comment: Hola Mateo, la funcion dibuja toda la linea dandole dos puntos que en este caso son 4 ejes

Comment: hola PaperBirdMaster, en otras palabras estoy calculando mal la pendiente para cuando x0<x1 && y0<y1?, luego el codigo de mi ingeniero era mas largo y se repetia practicamente dos veces el mismo pero cambiando los calculos de dx y dy y trate de redurirlo usando operadores ternarios.

Answer (score 1):

Sobre tu pregunta, lo que ves es parte del método que elegiste para dibujar las líneas.

La solución por la que puedes optar es, como parece que intentaste hacer, expresar la ecuación en términos de **x** o **y** según la pendiente de la línea.

Reescribiendo tu código de forma más legible tendrías algo así:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <utility>

void dibujarLinea(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1)
{
    float m = 0;

    // Si son iguales se dividiría entre 0, cosa que no queremos.
    if (x0 != x1)
        m = (y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0);

    // Si m es menor que 1 significa que la línea es más horizontal
    // y no habrá espacios si la dibujas iterando x.
    if (x0 != x1 && abs(m) < 1.0f)
    {
        if (x0 > x1){
            std::swap(x0, x1);
            std::swap(y0, y1);
        }

        // Si te das cuenta, como estamos incrementando x por una cantidad fija,
        // y también. Entonces puedes reducir el número de cálculos
        // sumando ese mismo número cada vez
        float dY = (y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0);
        float y = y0;

        for (float x = x0; i < x1; x++)
        {
            Form1->Canvas->Pixels[(int)x][(int)y] = clRed;
            y += dY;
        }
    }
    // Sino la dibujas iterando y
    else
    {
        if (y0 > y1){
            std::swap(x0, x1);
            std::swap(y0, y1);
        }

        float dX = (x1 - x0) / (y1 - y0);
        float x = x0;

        for (float y = y0; i < y1; y++)
        {
            Form1->Canvas->Pixels[(int)x][(int)y] = clRed;
            x += dX;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Si no estuvieras sujeto a hacerlo de este modo, hay algunas alternativas que puedes elegir.

La más simple que tienes es usar GDI+ para dibujar gráficos 2D. Aquí un ejemplo de [la documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusgraphics/nf-gdiplusgraphics-graphics-drawline(constpen_real_real_real_real)):

```
VOID Example_DrawLine4(HDC hdc)
{
    Graphics graphics(hdc);

    // Creas la lapicera con la que vas a dibujar.
    Pen blackPen(Color(255, 0, 0, 0), 3);

    // Defines las coordenadas de los puntos de inicio y fin de la línea.
    REAL x1 = 100.0f;
    REAL y1 = 100.0f;
    REAL x2 = 500.0f;
    REAL y2 = 100.0f;

    // Dibujas la línea.
    graphics.DrawLine(&blackPen, x1, y1, x2, y2);
}
```

Una tercera y muy buena opción es dibujar con shaders mediante alguna API gráfica como OpenGL o Vulkan (compatibles con casi cualquier sistema operativo), DirectX (para Windows y otros productos de Microsoft) o Metal (para Mac y otros dispositivos de Apple).

- **Ventaja**: Aprovechas la potencia de tu GPU.
- **Desventajas**: Son más difíciles de aprender a usar y hay poco material en español. Además necesitarás una buena base de álgebra lineal si tu interés está en los gráficos 3D.

Comment: Es una muy buena solucion, pero el motivo por el cual hago el uso de la ecuacion de pendiente es que estoy llevando a hacer las graficas desde cero en mi univesidad, y no nos permiten usar librerias especializadas para hacerlo.

Comment: Ya edité la pregunta. Eso debería solucionar tu problema. Aprovecho a compartir un video que quizá te sea útil https://youtu.be/PahbNFypubE